# simple Javascript For Loop with if else statement

Tags: javascript

I am new to js and I am trying out what I think should be a simple for loop. Basically I have a table with some strings in it and I want to change the background color of that table data column depending on the string.

Here is what I have

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  if (document.getElementById("td" + [i]).innerText == "TRUE") {
    document.getElementById("td" + [i]).style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("td" + [i]).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

It might be worth mentioning that the innerText is actually an API response that already uses an if statement inside a for loop

```html
<?php
  for ($i=0; $i < 50 ; $i++) {
    $type = $logs[$i]['type'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td id="td' .$i. '">';
    if ($type == 2) {
      echo "TRUE";
      echo '<br />';
    }
    else {
      echo "FALSE";
    }
    echo '</td>';
```

I am sure my code is wrong on many levels but it is working excep trying to run the for loop and change the background color. I don't think the js is correct in picking up the td0, td1, td2, etc.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please click edit, then scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add relevant HTML, CSS and framework in a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think a JS snippet is necessary here (without HTML at least, but their HTML comes preprocessed by PHP)...

Comment: It is not a PHP question so instead of posting PHP, dylzee should post the rendered HTML so we do not have to create it to show the solution

Comment: @mplungjan That's a good idea ;)

Comment: Sorry for my total newb post guys, I will take all suggestions on board for my next post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Your loop likely does not work because of the `<br/>` in the cell which makes the test false

```
if (document.getElementById("td" + [i]).innerText == "TRUE") {
```

You can fix that with with a [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim)

```
if (document.getElementById("td" + [i]).innerText.trim() == "TRUE") {
```

Also if you do not HAVE 50 cells, you will get an error

**Fixed code**

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  if (document.getElementById("td" + [i]).innerText.trim() == "TRUE") {
    document.getElementById("td" + [i]).style.backgroundColor = "green";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("td" + [i]).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody id="table1">
    <tr>
      <td id="td0">TRUE<br/></td>
      <td id="td1">TRUE<br/></td>
      <td id="td2">FALSE</td>
      <td id="td3">TRUE<br/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

**PHP Alternative**

You can just do this in the PHP - add classes - I am not sure I understand if you have ONE row with 50 cells?

```
<style>
.green {
  background-color: green
}

.red {
  background-color: red
}
</style>

<?php
  for ($i=0; $i < 50 ; $i++) {
    $type = $logs[$i]['type'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td id="td' .$i. '"';
    if ($type == 2) echo ' class="green">TRUE';
    else echo ' class="red">FALSE';
    echo '</td>';
  }
```

---

**Better client code:**

1. I gave the tbody an ID
2. I loop over all cells in the tbody, trimming (you have a br in there)
3. I use a class instead of setting the background color directly.

Benefit: No need to hardcode the number of cells and no need to have an ID on each

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => { // when the page loads
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#table1 tr td")].forEach( // convert the HTML collection to an array using the [...] spread operator
    cell => cell.classList.add(cell.innerText.trim() === "TRUE" ? "green" : "red")); // this construct is called a ternary
});
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green
}

.red {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody id="table1">
    <tr>
      <td>TRUE<br/></td>
      <td>TRUE<br/></td>
      <td>FALSE</td>
      <td>TRUE<br/></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you need to support older browsers you can do this instead

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { 
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll("#table1 tr td")
  for (let i=0;i<cells.length;i++) {
    const cell = cells[i];
    cell.classList.add(cell.innerText.trim() === "TRUE" ? "green" : "red")
  } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the contribution. I will go through and try all of your answers looking for a better way to output this. But for now, you were correct in saying that the <br /> was the problem so the .trim() worked beautifully. Thanks. Unfortunately, I can't upvote your answer because I still have (deservedly) have newb status. :)

Answer (score 1):

### you do simply like

```js
var cars = ["BMW", "TRUE", "Ford", "Audi"];
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  text += cars[i] + "<br>";
}


for (var j = 0; j < cars.length; j++) {
  if (cars[j] == "TRUE") {
    text += cars[i] + "<br> ";
    alert("set green here")
  } else {
    alert("set red here")
  }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript For Loop</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: What does your answer have to do with the question? You alert instead of setting color - the contents are already set to TRUE or FALSE. No cars involved. OP has a table with TRUE and FALSE.

Comment: Also your snippet is double for some reason. I fixed it for you

Comment: @dylzee if answer help accepts it.  dylzee it beginner so they easly  understand

Comment: they are likely more confused since your answer is not doing ANY of the things that were asked. No background color and OP's loop is already fine

Comment: I really do not want to vote your answer down, but really, it is not related to OP's code at all. See mine for comparison. Please improve your answer.